# Setting the transaction name for sentry does not have any effect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sentry

In our spring boot server we use Sentry for performance tracking. I want to set the transaction name of like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/command")
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class CqrsCommandRestController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/{command-name}", consumes ={ "application/json" }, produces = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<?> postCommand(
        @PathVariable("command-name") String cmdName,
        @RequestBody String body,
        Authentication auth
    ) throws InvalidCommandException, CommandNotProcessableException, CommandCurrentRessourceConflictException, NoPermissionException, EntityNotFoundException, MissingFieldException {
        // check command name
        if (cmdName == null) throw new InvalidCommandException("Command not defined.");
        if (!cmdName.endsWith("Command")) cmdName = cmdName.concat("Command");

        // configure sentry transaction (https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/spring-boot/enriching-events/transaction-name/)
        final String finalCmdName = cmdName;
        Sentry.configureScope(scope -> scope.setTransaction(finalCmdName));

       // ...   
   }

}
```

Setting the transaction name like this: `Sentry.configureScope(scope -> scope.setTransaction(finalCmdName))` unfortunately does not have any effect. All transactions of this controller are still shown like this:

[image]

My goal would be to see the different commands with different names, so instead of:

- POST /api/command/{command-name}

I want sentry to resolve the different commands:

- POST createUser
- POST deleteUser
- etc.

Comment: Not sure this is possible now. The transaction name at that point (not sure when you are calling your bits though) might be already frozen, even propagated downstream if you made a call to another service. That said, it sounds like a valid use case and probably a small change to make this possible. I suggest raising an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Platform%3A+Java%2CType%3A+Bug&template=bug_report_java.yml